# What is the use of addExpressionFieldToSelect over addFieldToSelect?

Tags: collection, magento-1

I'm studying Magento and I don't really understand what is the use of `addExpressionFieldToSelect` over `addFieldToSelect`? I haven't found the answer anywhere in my reading. As far as I can tell, it seems to be rewriting field names--but only if you pass in an array with the rewrite. Why couldn't you just do this with addFieldToSelect in the first place, if you know what the field should be rewritten as?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `addExpressionFieldToSelect()`, you can pass a `Zend_Db_Expr` instance with an arbitrary SQL expression.

So for example, this is possible with `addExpressionFieldToSelect()`, but not with `addFieldToSelect()`:

```
$collection->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
    'name_in_upper_case',
    new Zend_Db_Expr('UPPER(name)'),
    []
);
```

and results in an SQL query with

```
SELECT UPPER(name) as name_in_upper_case FROM ...
```

The placeholders for fieldnames are just syntactic sugar on top.